# Why are my keyframes disabled

Tags: animation

[image]

Why are the keyframes darkened on the timeline? It prevents me from editing them or changing values in them. I have been using blender for over a year now and have never seen this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might have locked them somehow. Open the "channel outliner" by dragging the little ">" to the right and have a look at the lock icons:

[image: locked channels]

Comment: I don't realize why that didn't occur to me...thanks